# How to integrate a python file onto a Django project?

Tags: python, django, opencv

I am trying to include a machine learning component in my Django project. I have the method written in python. How do I get to make it work on the website using Django. Can I simply drag the ".py" file into the file structure and call it from an HTML page? I am new to Django any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can directly copy file into your Django Directory structure. Let's say you have a file `test.py` and a function written in it as `def print()`. And you have copied the file in `app` directory. Then you can call it in views.py as `from app.test import print`. `print` function will be imported in views.py and you can use it to serve in html as you want.